# SSO Authentication

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, openam

I need some guidance on my SSO implementation.
I have done couple of SAML2 implementations with success but there is something missing on this one :-O I believe it is minor but I am not sure what I am missing and I not seeing much information in the logs on the agent side :-/

So :

- IDP Initiated
- I am the SP Using OpenAm 10
- Using J2EE Agent
- Same configuration works on prod as well for other clients
- SAML 2 implementation
- The cross domain is enable
- Certificate is loaded in the client IDP Metadata on my side

The issue is when I get the Response from the Vendor, they get redirected by the CDCSERVLET to the Login Page of OpenAm .. I am not getting why they are not authenticated.

Here the response:

```
<Response ID="_FAD290A87DB14BC4A8A8F435DEBDEBB3" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2015-12-31T20:59:34.1012911Z" Destination="https://sso.com:443/sp/Consumer/metaAlias/xxx-test/sp" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">xxx</Issuer>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <SignedInfo>
                               <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                                <Reference URI="#_FAD290A87DB14BC4A8A8F435DEBDEBB3">
                                            <Transforms>
                                                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                            </Transforms>
                                            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                            <DigestValue>HPTUTyPjegeyjDW5lmMb8ggbwas=</DigestValue>
                                </Reference>
                    </SignedInfo>
                    <SignatureValue>4Ek0xpDPj5Q==</SignatureValue>
        </Signature>
        <Status>
                    <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
        </Status>
        <Assertion Version="2.0" ID="_BCA1E13E205E4CDCB7AB903E90606DBD" IssueInstant="2015-12-31T20:59:34.1012911Z" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
                    <Issuer>xxx</Issuer>
                    <Subject>
                                <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified">100</NameID>
                                <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                                            <SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2015-12-31T21:04:34.1948917Z" Recipient="https://sso.com:443/sp/Consumer/metaAlias/xxx-test/sp"/>
                                </SubjectConfirmation>
                    </Subject>
                    <Conditions NotBefore="2015-12-31T20:54:34.1012911Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-12-31T21:04:34.1012911Z">
                                <AudienceRestriction>
                                            <Audience>xxx-test:saml2</Audience>
                                </AudienceRestriction>
                    </Conditions>
                    <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-12-31T20:59:34.1012911Z">
                                <SubjectLocality Address="000.0.0.000"/>
                                <AuthnContext>
                                            <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
                                </AuthnContext>
                    </AuthnStatement>
                    <AttributeStatement>
                                <Attribute Name="AIN">
                                            <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">100</AttributeValue>
                                </Attribute>
                    </AttributeStatement>
        </Assertion>
```

What I noted in that assertion is :

- There is no certificate in the Signature (All my client have the
   in the signature with the certificate)

On my side for the SP, I made sure that:

- The Authentication Context is set to Password to match the assertion
- I Disable the Federation if the NameId is Unspecified and I use the NameId as UserId

All of that should be good on my side, and I do not understand why the client gets redirected to the login page of OpenAM

Any help would be awesome !!

Thanks !

EDIT :

So, I had the vendor modified the assertion to send the `<NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">xxxx</NameID>`
And I added a user to the realm, and use it as transient user in my SP configuration but it resulted in the same issue !!

When the nameid-format was set as unspecified, I created that 100 user in the realm as a subject but it still did not work :-/

EDIT 3 : Here some information on the Session:

```
<SessionNotification vers="1.0" notid="117627">
<Session sid="AQIC5wM2LY4SfcxfxdL6szA_aGlQEkFtHROifZHX_VpqHag.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABM3OTI1OTk2NjE0MDA1MjA2MTcw*" stype="user" cid="id=user-test,ou=user,dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org" cdomain="dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org" maxtime="60" maxidle="30" maxcaching="5" timeidle="1800" timeleft="1529" state="destroyed">
<Property name="CharSet" value="UTF-8"></Property>
<Property name="UserId" value="user-test"></Property>
<Property name="FullLoginURL" value="/sp/UI/Login?ForceAuthn=false&amp;MinorVersion=0&amp;RequestID=see601a9040131cc9c9d09947cf1addab3e4df292&amp;refererservlet=https%3A%2F%2Fs-----6ForceAuthn%3Dfalse%26ProviderID%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fstagingcng.inspirus365.com%253A443%252F%253FRealm%253D%25252F%26MinorVersion%3D0%26Federate%3Dfalse%26IssueInstant%3D2016-01-12T21%253A30%253A22Z%26MajorVersion%3D1&amp;IssueInstant=2016-01-12T21%3A30%3A22Z&amp;MajorVersion=1"></Property>
<Property name="successURL" value="/sp/console"></Property>
<Property name="cookieSupport" value="true"></Property>
<Property name="AuthLevel" value="0"></Property>
<Property name="SessionHandle" value="shandle:AQIC5wM2LY4SfcwZfnMFJVMF0olMGhmq-Nmqw_BMxoVv4AA.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABM3OTI1OTk2NjE0MDA1MjA2MTcw*"></Property>
<Property name="UserToken" value="user-test"></Property>
<Property name="loginURL" value="/sp/UI/Login"></Property>
<Property name="Principals" value="user-test"></Property>
<Property name="Service" value="ldapService"></Property>
<Property name="sun.am.UniversalIdentifier" value="id=user-test,ou=user,dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org"></Property>
<Property name="amlbcookie" value="01"></Property>
<Property name="Organization" value="dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org"></Property>
<Property name="Locale" value="en_US"></Property>
<Property name="HostName" value="205."></Property>
<Property name="AuthType" value="DataStore"></Property>
<Property name="Host" value="205."></Property>
<Property name="UserProfile" value="Ignore"></Property>
<Property name="clientType" value="genericHTML"></Property>
<Property name="AMCtxId" value="a0749ff708bff14202"></Property>
<Property name="SessionTimedOut" value="1452636294"></Property>
<Property name="authInstant" value="2016-01-12T21:30:33Z"></Property>
<Property name="Principal" value="id=user-test,ou=user,dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org"></Property>
</Session>
```

The thing that struck me is the `<Property name="AuthType" value="DataStore"></Property>` (I have Federation from other vendors :0)
I am sure that the issue is because the user cannot get authenticated against OpenAM.

Comment: Enable 'message' level debug logging on OpenAM and check the Federation debug log. It will tell you why SAML WebSSO was not successful and hence no OpenAM SSO Session was created, which in turn made the CDCServlet redirect the user for authentication.

Comment: Hello Bernhard, Thank you for chipping in ! Yes , this is first thing I always do, turn up the log on the Agent and on OpenAM. There is nothing in the Federation and the Agent does not talk to me :-/ I am not seeing anything in particular ! - I edited the question with the log in case !

Comment: You don't have to look at the Agent first. Using Agents is the proprietary way of implementing Web-based SSO with OpenAM. SAML is the standards-based way of implementing Web-based SSO. You are mixing both ways here. First concentrate on the SAML side of things.

The SP has to process the SAML AuthnRequest response, issued by the IdP. The response will show up in Federation debug log on OpenAM side when debug level is set to 'message'. If it does not show up, the SAML response does not reach OpenAM. In that case use SAML tracer plugin first to inspect SAML protocol flow.

Comment: Have a look at OpenAM's doc to see how you can start/perform SP- or IdP-iniatiated WebSSO, without involving the Agent. If this works, go forward and include the Agent-protected resource into the flow.

Comment: Hey Berhnard, I get that the agent is not part of SAML and they are not part of the issue but that's the only place I get log information ... I confirmed that the Assertion is being posted to my Consumer URL with no problem, with the SAML Response. There is absolutely nothing in the Federation log ... (Yes it is turned up to message !) I confirmed that if I use the user I created in the realm that I had set up as Transient when they got that OpenAM login page, they get redirected properly to the Target URL.

Comment: When you use SAML Web SSO, not account linking, you normally don't get a login page on the SP side ?!?
I understood you have OpenAM acting as SAML SP and OpenAM policy agents which are using that OpenAM (for proprietary Web SSO / authorization).
If this understanding  correct?

Comment: That is correct, the account linking is done using a transient user , but I do not save anything in the user profile - It is set as ignored.

Comment: Also, I am wondering, if the Assertion was properly posted to us, no matter what, I should see that Assertion in the Federation log, correct ? As of today, I do not, and I am wondering if the assertion or the headers are stripped or something and that;s why I does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ... Turned out everything was set up right but our partner was posting the Assertion to the Relay/Target URL and not the Consumer URL .....

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that autofederation is turned off on the Service Provider side (OpenAM) and that you are using the NameID as the User ID.

After receiving the assertion the SP Account Mapper will try to find a user with that User ID in the Data Store for the Realm where the SP is defined. You can find which LDAP attribute is mapped to the User ID by going to Access Control > YOUR REALM > Data Stores > YOUR DATASTORE. Look for a property called "LDAP Users Search Attribute".

In this particular case the NameID value is "100", thus, the Account Mapper will try to find a user in your datastore with that User Id. For example, if your "LDAP Users Search Attribute" is set to "uid", the Account Mapper will try to find a user in your Directory whose "uid" is equal to "100".

So my assumption is that the Account Mapper is not able to map the incoming assertion to a valid user and it's taking you to the OpenAM's Login Page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Guillermo ! Thank you for helping me :) I had the AutoFederation disabled with the unspecified. I am trying to use the transient instead, with a specific user that I set up in that realm and see if it works. I have that working with couple of partners . I think you are right, the authentication is not happening against the Datastore I believe. Seems like even with the Transient it does not work :-/ Still getting that page ! Is there a way from the Response to manually call my SP so I can test different combination without the partner ?